# Cors error works with one configuration but not with other. Why?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

So I was experiencing a CORS error for the requests I was making from my react front end to my spring boot web flux back end. I intercept the requests in the backend and then extract some info from the requests using a filter and then the requests get authenticated. The security config is shown below. My question is that when I use a 'corsConfigurationSource' bean the CORS error is fixed and all my requests get completed as expected but when I use the
'corsConfigurer' bean I get the CORs error that I mentioned earlier. What is the difference between the two? I am applying the same filters to both configurations.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .cors().and()
                .addFilterAt(jwtTokenFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("read:Orders")
                .and().oauth2ResourceServer()            .jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()).and().and().build();
    }
```

The corsCinfigurationSource bean is shown below:

```
  @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

The corsConfigurer bean is shown below:

```
    @Bean
    public WebFluxConfigurer corsConfigurer(){
        return new WebFluxConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
                registry
                        .addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                        .allowCredentials(true)
                        .allowedHeaders("AUTHORIZATION", "CONTENT-TYPE", "X-AUTH-TOKEN")
                        .allowedMethods("GET","POST","OPTIONS");

            }
        };
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.